# Excel VBA: Remove everthing before/after a character except two characters to the right/left

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete everything in a cell before and after a certain character ('/' for example) but i want to keep 2 characters to left/right of "/" (eg: "......xx/yy....").
I know how to find and replace using asterisk('*') but that does'nt help me with keeping the 2 characters on the left/right

Comment: use `instr` and `mid`

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @norie  HbA1c Test Cartridge, 15 tests/kt (Continental US+HI Only) =  15 Tests/kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all occurrences by specifying `start` in a while loop [Instr doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

```
Sub trimString()
'modify char and range accordingly
Dim char: char = "/"
Dim rng: Set rng = Selection
Dim charPos: charPos = InStr(rng.Value, char)
Dim trimmedStr: trimmedStr = ""

While charPos > 0
    trimmedStr = trimmedStr & Mid(rng.Value, charPos - 2, 5)
    charPos = InStr(charPos + 1, rng.Value, char)
Wend
rng.Value = trimmedStr
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a ton your asnwer works really well, however in my case i have multiple "/" in my cells and the above code works on the first "/" it sees. will it be possible to execute it on all the "/" in a cell.  i have added a for loop to make it work across multiple cells at one but just want it to want get execute at every occurence of "/" in a cell

Comment: Edited my answer to work for multiple occurrences. You can add a delimiter or different treatment within the while loop